# Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает код(поэтапно, с описанием функций)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

```
>>> t = {str(d):d**5 for d in range(10)}
>>> sum(i for i in range(2, 200000) if i == sum(map(t.get, str(i))))
```

Я знаю, что этот код возвращает сумму всех чисел, сумма цифр в пятой степени которых равна самому этому числу. Но вообще не понимаю, как о действует после 10. Ведь на моменте

```
if i == sum(map(t.get, str(i)))
```

Получается `if 11 == sum(map(t.get, str(11)))` 
Но у нас в нашем сгенерированом словаре нет элемента под ключём 11. Что и говорить про 1589292, например.

Comment: `str` конвертирует число в строку. `map` работает по принципу `map(function_to_apply, list_of_inputs)` т.е. вызывается для каждого символа строки. ну дальше уже понятно думаю.

Comment: В том то и дело, что непонятно. Как мы применяем функцию` t.get` к ключу "17381", если в словаре сгенерированом всего лишь 10 элементов?

Comment: ещё раз смотрим на структуру `map` по сути строка это массив из символов. и `map` применяется к каждому символу. https://ideone.com/HKA4Bf

Comment: @pavel О, это я уже забыл, спасибочки!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите понять как это работает - попробуйте разбить решение на шаги и выполнять это по частям:

словарь с пятыми степенями:

```
In [65]: t
Out[65]:
{'0': 0,
 '1': 1,
 '2': 32,
 '3': 243,
 '4': 1024,
 '5': 3125,
 '6': 7776,
 '7': 16807,
 '8': 32768,
 '9': 59049}
```

как работает преобразование для одного числа - `123`

```
In [66]: list(map(t.get, str(123)))
Out[66]: [1, 32, 243]
```

теперь для нескольких чисел - `[123, 456, 789]`:

```
In [67]: [list(map(t.get, str(i))) for i in [123, 456, 789]]
Out[67]: [[1, 32, 243], [1024, 3125, 7776], [16807, 32768, 59049]]
```

следующий шаг - суммирование внутренних списков:

```
In [68]: [sum(map(t.get, str(i))) for i in [123, 456, 789]]
Out[68]: [276, 11925, 108624]
```

всё решение:

```
In [69]: [i for i in range(2, 200000) if i == sum(map(t.get, str(i)))]
Out[69]: [4150, 4151, 54748, 92727, 93084, 194979]
```

проверим пошагово для числа `4150`:

```
In [70]: list(map(t.get, str(4150)))
Out[70]: [1024, 1, 3125, 0]

In [71]: sum(map(t.get, str(4150)))
Out[71]: 4150
```